# Which development method to choose - Test-Driven or Behaviour Driven Development

Tags: agile, user-stories, development-process, bdd

In my current company, we follow DSDM.

But the maturity of the process is in progress and we are adapting various methods to be Agile.

Current Process:  Currently epics and user stories elaboration happen throughout the sprint and they are not detailed enough at the start of the sprint and stories get updated even after initial code development is completed.

With the above practise, which development approach will help the team?

Can we combine both methods for development?
BDD to ensure we gather enough requirements for the story and write the user acceptance test in the required format.
Use TDD to write test first and code.

Also considering the cost of delays in delivering user stories, which is the recommended approach to be Agile and deliver more?

Answer (score 4):

The practices are not mutually exclusive and, in fact, dove-tail together well. Unfortunately, it is unlikely that either will address the problem you state. Both BDD and TDD write tests as you go throughout the work. You still need to bound the backlog item. Most teams do this with acceptance criteria during backlog refinement or, at the latest, in sprint planning.